# What is the equivalence in definition? Dense set

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a topology notes and it defines proper dense sets $A$ as $cl(A) = X$ for $A \subset X$ for topological space $X$. I flipped to some analysis notes and they say dense sets in $\mathbf{R}$ are $A \cap (a,b) = \emptyset$ for every open set $(a,b)$.

What is the equivalence...? I mean how did a random open set pop up in the definition?

Comment: I hope you mean $cl(A) = X$.

Comment: @arkeet, yes that's what i mean

Comment: Hawk, do you mean $A\cap (a,b)$ is NONEMPTY?

Comment: @PVanchinathan, yes

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. If a set is truly dense, then it means its closure fills up the entire base space. This implies every open neighbourhood surely must contain those points. The equivalence is a matter of set inclusion proof. For brevity, just for completeness;

if $x \in cl(A) = X$, then every point belongs to every open set of $X$ and surely $A$. Conversely if $x \in A \cap U$ for open sets $U$ containing $x$, then surely $x \in cl(A).$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of closure for general topological spaces makes it almost trivial, for these statements are equivalent just by manipulation of sets:

- $\operatorname{cl}A = X$
- $C \text{ closed}, A \subseteq C \Longrightarrow C = X$
- $U \text{ open}, U \subseteq X \smallsetminus A \Longrightarrow U = \varnothing$
- $U \text{ open}, U \ne \varnothing \Longrightarrow X \cap U \ne \varnothing$.